# Moving React classes into separate files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After doing the [React tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) this is my index.html file:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="lib/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my src/main.jsx file:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
    var comments = this.state.data;
    var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
    this.setState({data: newComments});

    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: comment,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments Yo</h1>
        <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} />
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var author = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.author).value.trim();
    var text = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.text).value.trim();
    if (!text || !author) {
      return;
    }

    // send request to the server
    this.props.onCommentSubmit({author: author, text: text});
    React.findDOMNode(this.refs.author).value = '';
    React.findDOMNode(this.refs.text).value = '';
    return;
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" ref="author" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Say something..." ref="text" />
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment) {
      return (
        <Comment author={comment.author}>
          {comment.text}
        </Comment>
      );
    });
    commentNodes.reverse();
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
          {this.props.author}
        </h2>
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: rawMarkup}} />
        <hr />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <CommentBox url="comments.json" pollInterval={2000} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Additionally, I am running this command to turn my jsx into js:

```
babel --watch src/ --out-dir lib/
```

I would like to move each React class into its own file. For example, I would like to create the following four files (note: each map to a top level "var" declaration in my main.jsx file) and pull all of these classes into my main.jsx file:

```
comment.jsx
commentList.jsx
commentForm.jsx
commentBox.jsx
```

How do I do this?

After banging my head on require and es6 for a while here, I still do not have a good intuition of how to separate all these apart, or if something like require / es6 is even the right way to approach this.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to create a file for each React class, I would recommend to take a look at [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/). You can develop your React classes as CommonJs modules and it will take care of bundling them together.

Also, I think it is a good option because you want to use *babel* to transform your *jsx* files. This is solved with [webpack loaders](http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html).

The basic webpack configuration file would contain something like this:

*webpack.config.js*

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.jsx',
  output: {
    // Output the bundled file.
    path: './lib',
    // Use the name specified in the entry key as name for the bundle file.
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        // Test for js or jsx files.
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    // Don't bundle the 'react' npm package with the component.
    'react': 'React' 
  },
  resolve: {
    // Include empty string '' to resolve files by their explicit extension
    // (e.g. require('./somefile.ext')).
    // Include '.js', '.jsx' to resolve files by these implicit extensions
    // (e.g. require('underscore')).
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

I created a GitHub [react-tutorial-webpack](https://github.com/dreyescat/react-tutorial-webpack) repository if you want to have actual code.

Comment: this worked perfectly! thanks for the github link to your tutorial. it's answers like this that make me love Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 47):

In a project created with the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) tool separating components seems to work fine like this. Define the component in a file `Hello.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <p>Hello world!</p>
    );
  }
});

// Must export!
export default Hello;
```

And then you can import the component in another file with

```
import Hello from './Hello.jsx'
```

Comment: Sometimes the simplest answer is the best one. I was having the same problem with create-react-app, and you showed me that I need "./" at the beginning of the module name to import it.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Short, simple and without the use of extra bells and whistles.

Comment: `export default class MyClass extends Component {...}` works for me without any additional variables.

Comment: for me this worked fine, except that I need to use `Hello.js` instead of `Hello.jsx`.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion ES6 can be a way to write classes and module but not really to manage them.
For the purpose of managing modules I would use requirejs, simplest module manager that I know. But maybe other people will advise something else.

IMO you need a module manager and requirejs is a great tool for that.

**Update**:
Basically for requirejs you'll write a main.js file (which is a conf file for require, defining the paths of modules and first thigns to load)
In your main html you'll write something like this to load the main.js

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

Inside your views you'll call the module you need using define('MyModule'...) using the name you previously defined in the main.js (with the path).

**Read the doc,** don't worry this is not that terrible: 
http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html#add
**Here is a simple example**:
https://github.com/volojs/create-template

The way to break your code is pretty easy you'll return (this how you export a module with define()) your reactclass.
**Create one file for each class you have**. But you can also create module/utils to gather transverse functions (parsing...etc).

Hope it helps!

Comment: word up! could you send along a snippet of how to use require and separate these classes?

Comment: The example here https://github.com/volojs/create-template is really simple it just be enough to guide you through require basics.